# Scroll area in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js

I have a page in js . I wish that whenever I scroll I define how much of the page is scrolled . I **don't** want that I handle the scroll event , keep a state of old location , detect direction and then move to the required position .

Is there a way to define a fixed scroll height when  scroll via mouse or press up/down arrow key or press up/down in scroll button

EDIT:
FOUND
https://codepen.io/andyadams/pen/omLOqZ

```
.y-mandatory {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

however  y snap  does'nt work . X axis works but not y

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible directly in JS, the "scroll height" for the mouse wheel can be set in OS mouse settings (at least in Windows). If you want a JS solution, you've to implement your own scrolling methods, which will fall back to various events.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: added what i found . X snap works but not y snap . i can go in between 1 and 2